# <namespace> is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, namespaces, syntax-error

I hate checking Boolean to see there state and then toggling them based on it so I wrote something to do it for me.

It keeps giving me the following error:
 is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Here is the namespace and class:

```
namespace Bool
{
    public class ToggleState
    {

        static bool Toggle(bool Bool)
        {
            if (Bool == true)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code that's giving the error

```
Test = Bool.ToggleState(Test);
```

Comment: Don't share names between namespaces, classes, methods, variables, etc.

Comment: Don't get your code... it seems you should be using `Test = Bool.ToggleState.Toggle(Test);`

Comment: Did you actually mean just
    "return !Bool;"
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your namespace is called "Bool", wich makes it a type.

I refactored it a bit for you.

```
namespace Bool //Your namespace, it's a type
{
    public class ToggleState // Your class, also a type
    {
        static bool Toogle(bool boolValue) 
        {
            return !boolValue; //revert bool value and return it back
        }
    }
}
```

Name Bool (Your current namespace) can be easly mistaken with struct bool (variable type). Consider giving it more meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no question that namespace naming is not exactly the best, I don't see any reason for that to not work if you fix a couple of things:

1) You should have `Test = Bool.ToggleState.Toggle(Test);`

2) `Toggle` method should be public